# Как сохранить Cookies в WebView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

Нужно, чтобы логин и пароль сохранялись при выходе из приложения, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с cookies в Android есть класс [`CookieManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager).

Чтобы принимать cookies от сайтов, есть переключатель (по-умолчанию он уже включен):

```kotlin
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true)
```

Если вам нужно включить [third-party cookies](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie#%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_cookie), то есть следующий метод:

```kotlin
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)
```

В случае принудительной остановки приложения может возникнуть ситуация, что cookies не успели синхронизироваться на диск из оперативной памяти.

Поэтому, чтобы гарантированно сохранить cookies на диск, используйте метод [`flush()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager#flush()):

```kotlin
CookieManager.getInstance().flush()
```

Выполнение метода `flush()` можно добавить в ваш `WebViewClient`, чтобы сохранение cookies происходило после каждой загрузки страницы:

```kotlin
class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush()
    }
}
```

Не забудьте подключить ваш `WebViewClient` к `WebView`:

```kotlin
val webView = WebView(context)
webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
```